# Describe the image of $|z-2i|=2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Describe (as fully as possible) the image of $|z-2i|=2$ under the function $f(z)=\frac 1 z$.

I'm not actually sure what this is asking, but I did the mapping into the w plane and came up with $2iw -2i \bar{w}=-1$ which I believe is a line. Am I on the right track here?

$|z-2i|=2 \implies |z|^2-2i\bar z +2iz+4=4$

$\implies |z|^2-2i\bar z +2iz=0 \implies 1-2i \frac{1}{z} -2i \frac{1}{\bar z}=0$

$\therefore 2iw-2i \bar w =1$

Comment: I haven't checked your computations, but your ideas seem right.  The image is definitely a line, but it won't be easy to see that until you learn about Mobius transformations.

Comment: $|z-2i|=2 \implies |z|^2-2i\bar z +2iz+4=4$ **or** $z=0.$ The equation $2iw-2i \bar w =1 $ is equivalent to $4i \Im{(w)}=1$ and has no roots.